# Does Buddha bless all human beings?

Tags: the-buddha

Unlike all other gods and deities, Buddha blesses everyone on this earth without caring who is believing in his techniques (Buddha, Dhamma and Sangha). But god wouldn't bless someone unless he starts praying.

I read about Buddha and his Dhamma from Dr. B. R. Ambedkar. God wouldn't bless unless you wouldn't pray. God is just like wanting bribe from the worshiper, god examines it's devotee. Also It wouldn't accept a person as his devotee unless he wouldn't convert his religion that god is made for.

But I'm sure Buddha blesses everyone and until now. Is Buddha still blessing us all human beings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Buddha's teaching continues to bless us so I suppose the Buddha is still blessing those that discovered his teaching.

The Buddha isn't magic. The Buddha's teaching blesses the one who practices the teaching. The teaching (AKA The Dhamma) isn't magic as well, it's practical and it's sober although magic can happen. Check this out:

Here from the Mangala Sutta are the concise answers given by The Buddha to the question,"What is a blessing"?

1. Not being around fools
2. Being around the wise
3. Remembering the honorable
4. Having one‘s abode in a suitable place for safe practice
5. Having done meritorious actions
6. The pursuit of higher understanding
7. Being rich in knowledge
8. Being rich in skill
9. to be highly restrained ethically
10. Using only well-spoken words
11. Supporting one's parents
12. Caring for the family
13. Unconfused actions
14. Generosity
15. Right living
16. Caring for one‘s relatives
17. Refraining from unskillful things
18. To abhor unwholeseome things
19. To avoid unwholesome things
20. To avoid intoxicants
21. Diligence in righteousness
22. Reverence
23. Humility
24. Contentment
25. Gratitude
26. Hearing the Dhamma at the right time
27. Patience
28. Compliance
29. Seeing the monks
30. Discussing the Dhamma
31. Self-restraint
32. A holy life
33. Seeing The Four Noble Truths
34. Realizing Nibbana
35. A heart not trembling, unshaken
36. A heart not trembling, sorrowless
37. A heart not trembling, stainless
38. A heart not trembling, secure
    (from Khuddaka Nikaya, Sutta Nipata 2.4)

The Buddha probably does bless even people that have never heard of the Buddha. The good karmic actions of Dhamma practice should have a ripple effect on many people. :) metta

Comment: the order from item 13-18 might be switched in positions.  No intention to nit pick, but I want to bring this quality in Buddha most people don't recognize, "organization of words-sukata vinnayo (welldone-order-discipline of words".  When Buddha talked Dhamma, he always say it with some sort of order never in random.  for example, 38 blessings from most basic number 1, to most sophisticated 38.  You can see level of sophistication changes.  Also when he talked about suffering realms, hell, animal, hungry ghost (this gives us idea that tho all bad, hungry ghost is better than animal realms.

Comment: things Buddha said were always in some orders.  This is one of great qualities in Buddha.  So when one hears dhamma that is somehow not in order, you can suspect it might not be Buddha's words.  Buddha said he would be mindful of every word spoken and only him had this quality.  Order of words is a subset of "sugato-great speaker".

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I think your right. I got this list from "The Complete Book of Buddha‘s Lists -- Explained" and I did a little editing because some things sounded a bit off. I was hoping someone might know a different translation.